# Read JSON data from sql server and convert to row and column

Tags: sql-server

```
 {
   "product": "car",
   "fuel": {
     "Maruti": {
         "Model": {
           "LXI": [
                 {
                     "Price": "700000"
                  }
              ],
           "VXI": [
                 {
                     "Price": "800000"
                 }
             ],
           "ZXI": [
                 {
                     "Price": "900000"
                 }
             ]
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

i have this JSON stored in SQL table and need t fetch it from CarDetails Table

table structure is as below:

```
ID
JSONData(this col has JSON stored)
CreatedDate
```

there can be more models as well like 10 or 20 or 1000....... I need all different prices for this in SQL Server. Can anyone assist
I need this data as:

```
700000
800000
900000
```

can anyone help me out in this.

I tried cross apply but it did not helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the model names as property keys complicates things slightly, but it's still possible to extract this data with multiple cross applies of the [OPENJSON()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql) function, e.g.:

```sql
declare @demo table (
  ID int,
  JSONData nvarchar(max)
);

insert @demo (ID, JSONData) values (47, N'{
  "product": "car",
  "fuel": {
    "Maruti": {
        "Model": {
          "LXI": [
                {
                    "Price": "700000"
                 }
             ],
          "VXI": [
                {
                    "Price": "800000"
                }
            ],
          "ZXI": [
                {
                    "Price": "900000"
                }
            ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}');

select ID, J.product, K.[key] as [Model], L.Price
from @demo
cross apply openjson(JSONData) with (
  product nvarchar(50),
  ModelJSON nvarchar(max) '$.fuel.Maruti.Model' as JSON
) J
cross apply openjson(J.ModelJSON) K -- default columns: [key],[value],[type]
cross apply openjson(K.[value]) with (
  Price nvarchar(10)
) L;
```

Which yields the results:

| ID | product | Model | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 47 | car | LXI | 700000 |
| 47 | car | VXI | 800000 |
| 47 | car | ZXI | 900000 |